# How add multiple rows with one Insert query in EF

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I have a **list of strings** of unknown length.
I'm adding them to database:

```
if (somenteNovasClas.Any()) {
    foreach (string item in wsClassificacoes) {
        dc.Classificacaos.Add(new Classificacao { Descricao = item });
    }
    dc.SaveChanges();
}
```

But EF will generate one `INSERT` for each row:

```
exec sp_executesql N'insert [dbo].[Classificacao]([Descricao], [Excluido])
values (@0, @1)
select [CodClassificacao]
from [dbo].[Classificacao]
where @@ROWCOUNT > 0 and [CodClassificacao] = scope_identity()',N'@0 varchar(255),@1 bit',@0='Mercado',@1=0
go
exec sp_executesql N'insert [dbo].[Classificacao]([Descricao], [Excluido])
values (@0, @1)
select [CodClassificacao]
from [dbo].[Classificacao]
where @@ROWCOUNT > 0 and [CodClassificacao] = scope_identity()',N'@0 varchar(255),@1 bit',@0='Concorrência',@1=0
go
```

I'd like to know how to insert in one time that EF will generate a command like:

```
INSERT INTO Table (column)
VALUES ([array[0]]), ([array[1]]), ...
```

instead of one insert foreach..
Any ideas?

Comment: How do you know EF is generating one insert for each row?

Comment: using [Express profiler](http://expressprofiler.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Fair enough. Please show your C# code. I suspect you are not writing it as intended by MSFT. I'm quite sure EF can do batch inserts.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. Unless you bulk insert from a SqlBulkCopy or an external data source, this is the only way it can be done AFAIK and the way you are doing it is still pretty fast.

Comment: You might want to write an SP or a UDF and use table value parameters to get the data to SQL Server in one hop... http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Stored-Procedure-with-6c194514

Comment: EF will never generate sql statements with so-called row constructors. It's just not one of its features.

Comment: ok... just checking, I was hoping that there was one more effective, this is poluting so much the profiler.. it's a lot of rows :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fastest Way of Inserting in Entity Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940225/fastest-way-of-inserting-in-entity-framework)

Comment: Possibly... except that I would like to know if there is a way to generate the script with EF, not just "the fastest" way to insert.

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework core (3+) has been improved significantly in this area. When there are multiple inserts that have the same shape, for Sql Server it will generate `MERGE` statements rather than separate `INSERT` statements.

For example, adding 10 new products:

```sql
DECLARE @inserted0 TABLE ([Id] int, [_Position] [int]);
MERGE [Products] USING (
VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, 0),
(@p5, @p6, @p7, @p8, @p9, 1),
(@p10, @p11, @p12, @p13, @p14, 2),
(@p15, @p16, @p17, @p18, @p19, 3),
(@p20, @p21, @p22, @p23, @p24, 4),
(@p25, @p26, @p27, @p28, @p29, 5),
(@p30, @p31, @p32, @p33, @p34, 6),
(@p35, @p36, @p37, @p38, @p39, 7),
(@p40, @p41, @p42, @p43, @p44, 8),
(@p45, @p46, @p47, @p48, @p49, 9)) AS i ([Image], [ProductName], [QuantityPerUnit], [StartDate], [UnitPrice], _Position) ON 1=0
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT ([Image], [ProductName], [QuantityPerUnit], [StartDate], [UnitPrice])
VALUES (i.[Image], i.[ProductName], i.[QuantityPerUnit], i.[StartDate], i.[UnitPrice])
OUTPUT INSERTED.[Id], i._Position
INTO @inserted0;

SELECT [t].[Id], [t].[RowVersion] FROM [Products] t
INNER JOIN @inserted0 i ON ([t].[Id] = [i].[Id])
ORDER BY [i].[_Position];
```

The concluding `SELECT` query is for feeding back the generated `Id` and `RowVersion` values into the C# objects.

When there are large numbers of inserts, EF won't hit the maximum parameter threshold, it just generates multiple blocks of `MERGE` statements.

It's not the same as an insert statement with value constructors, but still a lot better than countless separate inserts.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this post: [Fastest Way of Inserting in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940225/fastest-way-of-inserting-in-entity-framework)

Entity framework isn't really meant to do this out of the box, but it looks like people have created some extensions: https://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/